# NoSuchMethodError Couchbase 2.5.8 Spring Boot Startup Error

Tags: spring, couchbase

We are using Couchbase DB in our Spring boot application (Microservice) and it gives an NoSuchMethodError during the startup in PCF and application crashes

The Couchbase SDK used is 2.5.8

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.8</version>
            </dependency>
```

and the RxJava Version is 1.1.10 .

Creating the CouchbaseEnvironment using the following piece of code

```
            CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .sslEnabled(true).bootstrapHttpSslPort(18091)
            .sslKeystoreFile(Preconditions.checkNotNull(environment.getProperty("couchbase.ssl.keystore")))
            .sslKeystorePassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(environment.getProperty("couchbase.ssl.keystore.password")))
            .connectTimeout(50000)
            .kvTimeout(50000)
            .build();
```

And the exception we get is as following

```
            2018-05-18T16:02:56.889+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment]: Factory method 'couchbaseEnvironment' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment$Builder.kvEndpoints(I)Lcom/couchbase/client/java/env/DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment$Builder;
            2018-05-18T16:02:56.889+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            2018-05-18T16:02:56.889+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
            2018-05-18T16:02:56.889+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] ... 26 common frames omitted
            2018-05-18T16:02:56.889+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment$Builder.kvEndpoints(I)Lcom/couchbase/client/java/env/DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment$Builder;
            2018-05-18T16:02:56.889+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration$CouchbaseConfiguration.initializeEnvironmentBuilder(CouchbaseAutoConfiguration.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
            2018-05-18T16:02:56.889+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration$CouchbaseConfiguration.couchbaseEnvironment(CouchbaseAutoConfiguration.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.8.RELEASE]
```

Tried using the dependency available in Spring boot also but then getting  Time Out exception.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```

The Couchbase bucket is created as Service in PCF and Binded to service .

```
            [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/couchbase/CouchbaseAutoConfiguration$CouchbaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket]: Factory method 'couchbaseClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
            2018-05-18T12:46:22.497+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2018-May-18 07:16:22.496 WARN [cb-io-1-1] c.c.c.c.e.Endpoint - [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Generic Failure.
            2018-05-18T12:46:22.505+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2018-May-18 07:16:22.504 WARN [cb-io-1-1] c.c.c.c.e.Endpoint - null
            2018-05-18T12:46:22.520+05:30 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2018-May-18 07:16:22.519 WARN [cb-io-1-1] c.c.c.d.i.n.u.c.DefaultPromise - An exception was thrown by com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$4$1.operationComplete()
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to Spring Cloud dependencies. There was an upgrade in the PCF at our organization to latest version of Spring Cloud Dependencies and once i upgraded to the latest version it worked fine

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Earlier I was using the following version

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Once I updated these dependencies it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to upgrade `core-io` to 1.5.6 or later.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

`NoSuchMethodError` is thrown since [this change](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-java-client/commit/762c2dc4460720fc5d27719630694e8badc9cd10#diff-5c321e9c5d4bec4a286000165da7bbd8) has been committed.

See also:
https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/JVMCBC-495